# How do I create a directory from within Emacs?

Tags: emacs, directory, command

How exactly can I create a new directory using Emacs? What commands do I use? (If possible, please provide an example)

Answer (score 221, accepted):

- to create the directory `dir/to/create`, type:

  ```
  M-x make-directory RET dir/to/create RET
  ```
- to create directories `dir/parent1/node` and `dir/parent2/node`, type:

  ```
  M-! mkdir -p dir/parent{1,2}/node RET
  ```

  It assumes that Emacs's inferior shell is `bash`/`zsh` or other compatible shell.
- or in a `Dired` mode

  ```
  +
  ```

  It doesn't create nonexistent parent directories.

  Example:

  ```
  C-x d *.py RET ; shows python source files in the CWD in `Dired` mode
  + test RET     ; create `test` directory in the CWD
  ```

  `CWD` stands for Current Working Directory.
- or just create a new file with non-existing parent directories using `C-x C-f` and type:

  ```
  M-x make-directory RET RET
  ```

Emacs asks to create the parent directories automatically while saving a new file in recent Emacs versions. For older version, see [How to make Emacs create intermediate dirs - when saving a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6830671/4279)

Comment: Hi J.F. Sebastian, When I create a directory in shell , how to update the directory window ?

Comment: @why: type `g`. In general `M-x describe-mode RET` (`C-h m`) to display documentation of current major mode.

Comment: Thanks very much!  But you mean I input M-x g or C-x g  ?

Comment: @why he means a single `g`. Since `dired-mode` is not an editing mode, it uses single-letter commands directly (for the curious: `g` is bound to `self-insert-command` in most editing modes).

Comment: `C-x d *.py RET` is supposed to show python files? It says: "Reading directory: No such file or directory, /some/path/*.py".

Comment: @x-yuri: have you typed `C-x d *.py RET` or `C-x d /some/path/*.py RET`? The former works in my environment.

Comment: Oh, sorry, by the look of it I probably thought it would find python files in subdirectories as  well (recursively). To answer your question, it autosuggested the `/some/path/` part. And I believe I tried both back then.

Answer (score 52):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> (`C-x d`) to open a directory in "dired" mode, then <kbd>+</kbd> to create a directory.

Comment: I assume the '+' goes at the end of whatever the new file path directory is going to be?

Comment: when I do C-x C-f and enter "+ dirname" emacs creates a file "+ dirname", it does not create a directory "dirname". I am working with OSX, I don't know if that's the problem because in Linux this worked.

Comment: @Zeynel: You're not reading. There is no `C-x C-f` here. You use **`C-x d`** to get into Dired mode, visiting the directory where you want to create a subdirectory. Then you hit `+`. That's all.

Answer (score 9):

You can also run single shell commands using `M-!`

You're basically sending a string to the command line so you don't get any nice auto-completion but it's useful if you know how to perform an action through the command line but don't know an Emacs equivalent way.

```
M-! mkdir /path/to/new_dir
```

Comment: This works, type 'g' afterwards to update the screen contents.

Answer (score 7):

I guess I did it the hard way earlier today. I did:

```
M-x shell-command
```

then

```
mkdir -p topdir/subdir
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `make-directory` inside of any buffer, not necessarily a dired buffer.  It is a lisp function you can use as well.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question while searching for how to automatically create directories in Emacs. The best answer I found was in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830671/how-to-make-emacs-create-intermediate-dirs-when-saving-a-file) from a few years later. The answer from [Victor Deryagin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/513266/victor-deryagin) was exactly what I was looking for. Adding that code to your .emacs will make Emacs prompt you to create the directory when you go to save the file.