# How to make Emacs create intermediate dirs - when saving a file?

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to create folder tree in emacs - similar to

```
mkdir -p
```

in bash?

Basically - I want emacs to create all the intemediate dirs - if they were not existing - when I save a file.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155507/how-do-i-create-a-directory-from-within-emacs

Comment: I've re-formulated the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Function `make-directory` does that. Your particular problem may be solved like this:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when buffer-file-name
              (let ((dir (file-name-directory buffer-file-name)))
                (when (and (not (file-exists-p dir))
                           (y-or-n-p (format "Directory %s does not exist. Create it?" dir)))
                  (make-directory dir t))))))
```

Comment: It is a good idea for prompting to make new directories, rather than do it by default while saving.

Comment: aartist: replace `(make-directory dir t)` with `(when (y-or-n-p (format "Create directory?: %s " dir)) (make-directory dir t))`

Comment: @Adobe seems to work for me. Could you describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: Surely: when I save existing file in a non-existing dir -- everything works fine. But when I save a buffer - which is not corresponding to any existing buffer - emacs says: no such dir.

Comment: I meant - when I save a buffer - which is not corresponding to any existing FILE - emacs says: no such dir.

Comment: @Adobe Oh, I see. The problem is that function `basic-save-buffer` signals error before hook is run. Not sure how to handle this case correctly. I suggest using function `write-file` (bound to `C-x C-w` by default) for saving such buffers — everything will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just execute `mkdir -p` from inside emacs using `M-!` to get a shell command prompt.

Then all you have to do is put your directory structure in:

`M-! dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4.....`

Comment: How can I make this work? I enter `M-!` and then my minibuffer prompts me with `Shell command: ` but none of my commands are accepted. For example, entering `pwd` or `ls` I get messages like `pwd is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.`. Can you explain this with more detail please? (I am a bit novice to emacs)

Answer (score 2):

(make-directory DIR &optional PARENTS)

Create the directory DIR and any nonexistent parent dirs.
If DIR already exists as a directory, signal an error, unless PARENTS is set.